# Number of possible chains

Tags: combinatorics

Let $n>1$ be a fixed positive integer. Then find the number of possible chains of numbers $1<q_1<q_2<\ldots<q_t<n,t\geq 2$ such that atleast once $q_i-q_{i-1}>1$ for $2\leq i\leq t.$

Comment: Is $t$ fixed? Have you tried computing this for small values of $n$ to look for patterns?

Comment: Here $t$ is not fixed. I am trying but not getting it that is why i have posted here.

Comment: Is each $q_i$ a real number or an integer?

Comment: With $t\ge2$, you get $n\ge5$. So can you write down all the solutions with $n=5$? Can you write down all the solutions with $n=6$?

Comment: For $n=5,t=2$ there is only sequence $1<2<4<5.$

Comment: That's a good start. Now, $n=6$?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: I suspect that here, as in [your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2013608/number-of-sequences-of-positive-integers/2013753), you want $0<q_1$, not $1<q_1$, and I’ll write my answer on that basis. (If you really do want $1<q_1$, it’s an easy modification.) The only subsets of $[1,2,\ldots,n-1]$ of cardinality at least $2$ that do *not* satisfy the given condition are those of the form $\{k,k+1,\ldots,\ell\}$ for some integers $k$ and $\ell$ such that $1\le k<\ell\le n-1$. Thus, each of these bad subsets is completely determined by the pair of numbers $k$ and $\ell$.

- How many subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$ have at least $2$ elements?
- How many subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$ with at least $2$ elements do not satisfy the given condition?

Combine those results to get the desired answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each $q_i$ is an integer, we observe how many sequences are such that $q_i - q_{i-1} \gt 1$ never occurs.

If the above condition is false, then we have to have $q_i - q_{i-1} = 1$ for each $i$, as it is given that each $q_i$ is in strict ascending order.

Hence, the number of sequences so produced would be $n-t-1$

The total number of sequences are $n-2 \choose t$ , and therefore, we get number of chains as $$N(t) = {n-2 \choose t} - (n-t-1)$$

Comment: Take $n=5, t=2$. There is only one sequence $1<2<4<5.$ But according to your formula we are getting $2.$

Comment: Subtraction error :P.. .check now

Comment: Yaa now this seems correct

Comment: how you are getting $n-t-1$?

Comment: If you have $n$ integers, from $1$ to $n$, then, the number of consecutive sequences of length $t$ I can make from that, excluding $1,n$ would be $n-t-1$. Draw a number line and see for yourself