# Number of sequences of positive integers

Tags: combinatorics

Let $n>1$ be a fixed positive integer. Find the number of possible sequences of positive integers $0<j_1<j_2<\ldots<j_i<n,i\geq 1$ with exactly two $q'$s such that $j_q-j_{q-1}>1,q\geq 2.$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Basically you’re choosing a subset $A$ of $[n-1]=\{1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$ that consists of $3$ blocks of consecutive integers. Such a subset is completely determined by the $6$-tuple

$$\langle j_1,j_{q_1-1}+1,j_{q_1},j_{q_2-1}+1,j_{q_2},j_i+1\rangle\;,\tag{1}$$

where $q_1<q_2$ are such that $j_{q_1}-j_{q_1-1},j_{q_2}-j_{q_2-1}>1$.

A $6$-tuple $\langle a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6\rangle$ of elements of $[n]$ is of the form $(1)$ if and only if it is strictly increasing.

> **Examples.** Suppose that $n=7$; the $6$-tuple $\langle 2,3,4,5,6,7\rangle$ corresponds to $j_1=2$, $j_{q_1-1}+1=3$, $j_{q_1}=4$, $j_{q_2-1}+1=5$, $j_{q_2}=6$, and $j_i+1=7$, so $j_{q_1-1}=2$, $j_{q_2-1}=4$, and $j_i=6$. It follows that $q_1-1=1$, so $q_1=2$, and $j_2=4$. Thus, $q_2-1=2$, $q_2=3$, and $j_3=6.$ Finally, this means that $i=3$, and the sequence is $2<4<6$.
>
> The $6$-tuple $\langle 1,3,4,5,6,7\rangle$ corresponds to $j_1=1$, $j_{q_1-1}+1=3$, $j_{q_1}=4$, $j_{q_2-1}+1=5$, $j_{q_2}=6$, and $j_i+1=7$, so $j_{q_q-1}=2$, $j_{q_2-1}=4$, and $j_i=6$. The first block is therefore $12$, the second is $4$, and the third is $6$, the sequence being $1<2<4<6$.

In such a $6$-tuple $a_1$ is the first number in the first block, $a_2$ is the successor to the last number in the first block, $a_3$ is the first number in the second block, $a_4$ is the successor to the last number in the second block, $a_5$ is the first number in the last block, and $a_6$ is the successor to the last number in the last block.

Thus, you need only count the strictly increasing $6$-tuples from $[n]$.

Comment: Sir, one more question, what is the solution if $i$ is fixed?

Comment: @user389160: Yes, $\binom{n}6$ is correct. The situation when $i$ is fixed is quite different; it would be better to make that a new question.