# Number of possible chains of length $i$

Tags: combinatorics

Let $n\geq 6$ be a fixed positive integer. Then for a fixed $i$ such that $2<i<n$, find the number of possible chains $0<j_1<j_2<\ldots<j_i<n$ of length $i$ with exactly two $q's$ such that $j_{q}-j_{q-1}>1.$

Comment: Very similiar question exists
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2013248/number-of-possible-chains/2013298#2013298

Comment: Yes but here you need exactly two $q$'s.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you want to count the cardinal of the following set $$A_{i,n}=\{(a_1,\cdots , a_i)\in [n-1]^i:0<a_1<\cdots <a_i<n \wedge (\exists ! l,k (l\neq k))(a_l-a_{l-1}=a_k-a_{k-1}>1)\},$$
Consider the following set $$B_{i,n}=\{(b_1,b_2,\cdots , b_i,b_{i+1})\in [n-1]^{i+1}:\sum _{j=1}^ib_j=n \wedge b_1,b_{i+1}\geq 1 \wedge (b_j = 1 \text{ for all but $2$ index say $\color{red}{l,k}\in\{2,\ldots ,i\}$ }) \},$$
I claim that there is a bijection between the two sets (do you see why? **Hint:** $a_1=b_1$ and we are trying to encode how the chain grows)
The reason i do this change is because is easier to get $B_{i,n},$ you just have to set the $2$ index where is $b_j>1$ and see the possibilities for those numbers. So, first we choose the index, so we have to choose $2$ from $i-1$(see that $b_1,b_{i+1}$ are not imposed that condition) so the ways to do it are $$\binom{i-1}{2},$$
Now, we have to see what numbers we can place on $b_1,b_{i+1},b_{\color{red}{k}}$ and $b_{\color{red}{l}},$ but we know that $$b_1+b_{i+1}+b_{\color{red}{k}}+b_{\color{red}{l}}+\sum _{j\neq 1,i+1,k,l}\underbrace{b_j}_{\text{all of these are $1$'s}}=b_1+b_{i+1}+b_{\color{red}{k}}+b_{\color{red}{l}}+i-3=n,$$ so $$b_1+b_{i+1}+b_{\color{red}{k}}+b_{\color{red}{l}}=n-i+3,$$ with $b_1,b_{i+1}\geq 1$ and $b_{\color{red}{k}},b_{\color{red}{l}}\geq 2,$ so we set $b_{\color{red}{k}}=c_{\color{red}{k}}+1$ $b_{\color{red}{l}}=c_{\color{red}{l}}+1,$ so we have that $$b_1+b_{i+1}+c_{\color{red}{k}}+1+c_{\color{red}{l}}+1=n-i+3,$$
equivalent to 
$$b_1+b_{i+1}+c_{\color{red}{k}}+c_{\color{red}{l}}=n-i+1,$$

with $b_1,b_{i+1},c_{\color{red}{k}},c_{\color{red}{l}}\geq 1.$
This is classical **star and bars** so the number of ways to choose them is $$\binom{n-i}{3},$$
so by the rule of multiplication the answer is $$\binom{n-i}{3}\binom{i-1}{2}.$$
Hope it helps.